# Array + Loop for Month and Year combination

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

I am trying to create a array with the months Jan - Dec and i want to also have the year so it would look like "J14" for January. I want this to increase everything i run to it would move up to the next month and after 12 runs the year will then change to "J15". I will run this macro once a month which is why i want the month and to increase by 1 each time i run it. Below is what i have so far, please excuse if it is wrong as i never used arrays before

```
Sub test()
Dim MyArray(1 To 12) As Integer

MyArray(1) = J
MyArray(2) = F
MyArray(3) = M
MyArray(4) = A
MyArray(5) = M
MyArray(6) = J
MyArray(7) = J
MyArray(8) = A
MyArray(9) = S
MyArray(10) = O
MyArray(11) = N
MyArray(12) = D

For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)

Cells(i, 1).Value = MyArray(i)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you to learn about DataTypes first. A char can not be the content of an Int-Array. Furthermore, i dont really understand your question. Will you trigger this makro once a Year or how does it work?

Comment: trigger it once a month, so it should increase 1 month per month. I will look into datatypes. Thanks. I see what you mean about the char now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it would work, if you simply write "14" in range A13. But it is really a good idea that you learn Data Types as the first comment has proposed. Furthermore, there are many better ways to do it. But still:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim i                   As Long
    Dim MyArray(1 To 12)    As String

    MyArray(1) = "J"
    MyArray(2) = "F"
    MyArray(3) = "M"
    MyArray(4) = "A"
    MyArray(5) = "M"
    MyArray(6) = "J"
    MyArray(7) = "J"
    MyArray(8) = "A"
    MyArray(9) = "S"
    MyArray(10) = "O"
    MyArray(11) = "N"
    MyArray(12) = "D"

    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)

        Cells(i, 1).Value = MyArray(i) & Cells(13, 1)

    Next i

    Cells(13, 1) = Cells(13, 1) + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: hi thanks, that is very useful. I noticed know what i did with the datatypes and not declaring i as well.

Comment: this displays all 12 arrays at once, is there a way to only display 1 array per run so i would need to run the macro 12 times to get the full array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub test()
Dim MyArray(1 To 12) As String '<--| you need to deal with "strings" (like "J"), not "integers"

MyArray(1) = "J" '<--| strings must be enclosed in quotation marks
MyArray(2) = "F"
MyArray(3) = "M"
MyArray(4) = "A"
MyArray(5) = "M"
MyArray(6) = "J"
MyArray(7) = "J"
MyArray(8) = "A"
MyArray(9) = "S"
MyArray(10) = "O"
MyArray(11) = "N"
MyArray(12) = "D"

For j= 14 To 20 '<--| set here your year range
   For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)    
    Cells(i, 15-j).Value = MyArray(i) & CStr(j")   '<--| concatenate the month string with the year number
   Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char monthArray[] = {"J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D"};

for (int j = 00 ; j  < 20 ; j ++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12, i++) {
        char month = monthArray[i];
        String myNotation = "month" + j;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, it's C. But that logic can solve his problem.

Comment: i was confused, not seen C since college. Thanks for help anyway